# $f\in L^1\cap L^2$ implies $\hat f \in L^1$?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Given $f\in L^1(\mathbb R^d)\cap L^2(\mathbb R^d)$. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma and the unitarity of the Fourier transform on $L^2$ implies that $\hat f \in L^2\cap C_0$ where $C_0$ are continuous functions decaying at infinity.
My professor claimed that $\hat f\in L^1$ which is not obvious in my opinion.

Is this correct?

Comment: well we know $\hat f \in L^2 \cap C_0^0 \cap L^\infty $ but this conditions alone do not suffice to say $\hat f \in L^1$. So if it is indeed that way I don't think it descends directly from the Riemann Lebesgue lemma. Wait for more experienced people to answer though! :)

Comment: Indeed, $g(x) = \dfrac{1}{1 + |x|}$ belongs to $L^2 \cap C_0$ on the line but is not in $L^1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not true.

Simply take $f = \chi_{[-1,1]}$ (the indicator function of the interval $[-1,1]$). Then $f \in L^p$ for all $p \in (0,\infty]$, but if $\widehat{f} \in L^1$ was true, then Fourier inversion would imply that

$$
f = \mathcal{F}^{-1} \widehat{f} \in C_0
$$

would be (almost everywhere equal to) a continuous function. This is clearly not the case.

Answer (score 3):

Your professor is wrong and Umberto P. is right. If we take
$$ f(x)= K_0(|x|) $$
where $K_0$ is a [modified Bessel function of the second kind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function), we have $f\geq 0$ and: 
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}K_0(|x|)\,dx = \pi,\qquad \int_{0}^{+\infty}K_0(|x|)^2\,dx = \frac{\pi^2}{2},$$
so $f\in L^1\cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$, but:
$$ \widehat{f}(s) = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+s^2}} $$
does not belong to $L^1(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: Why the downvote? The counter-example is perfectly fine.